# Cant turn on WiFi only Ethernet

Tags: wifi, hardware

Hi guys i cant seem to turn on my WiFi at all. I can only connect through Ethernet it seems. I'm curious if I didn't download Elementary correctly. When I goto wifi it wont turn on after i select it. When I see the options for the wifi card it appears but in gray. Im trying to use my WiFi adapter but i cant even find the drivers for it. Any help would be awesome i'm stumped and tried everything from forums to even switching to mint and Ubuntu but none of them can get my wifi to work.

(also the wifi adapter is Panda 300Mbps Wireless N USB Adapter)

Thanks again